# How can I connect Lighthouse tickets to Eclipse Mylyn?

Tags: eclipse, mylyn, lighthouse

I of course came across [this](http://help.lighthouseapp.com/discussions/tips-tricks/25-integrating-eclipse-mylyn-with-lighthouse) but without any success, I used the pattern from the screenshot (and comments) but I'm still getting empty task list (see attachment). I examined the pattern and compared it to Lighthouse tickets.xml, and it all seems correct.

[image: Task repository]

Answer (score 0):

Does [this blog post](http://scotth.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/eclipse-mylyn-with-lighthouseapp-com/) help? I outline a few extra steps beyond the Lighthouseapp help doc you already found.